# Unexpected = error in if statement

Tags: php

okay, I guess I'm tired because I just can't find the syntax error with this.

```
<option value="1" <?php if($row['courseId'] == '1') echo selected="selected"; ?>>NAME</option>
```

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';'
```

What did I forget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<option value="1" <?php if($row['courseId'] == '1') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>NAME</option>
```

You didn't put your output in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be quoted:

```
echo 'selected="selected"';
```